# Correctly typing React Hooks?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

What is the correct (or at least idiomatic) way to type a state hook in TypeScript?

Is it

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState( [] as SomeType[] )
```

or

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState<SomeType[]>( []  )
```

or something else? Or are there really no meaningful differences among the options?

Comment: `const [items, setItems] = useState( new Array<SomeType>() )` might be an option. Other than that IMHO it's up to you, pick one use it everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The main diff between those is that typescript is pulling the type from the value rather than you giving it directly to the useState hook.

There's no correct way of doing it, but it might be more readable if you stick to option two..

An example where it gives a reason to stick with option two is for example when you initialize the state value by giving it a function

```js
const [items, setItems] = useState<SomeType[]>(() => someExpensiveWayOfGettingTheValue...);
```

Another reason to stick with option two is when you're not wanting to provide an initialValue

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState<Sometype>();
```

Comment: The second option also feels more explicit somehow (even providing the opportunity to catch a wrong type initialization).

Comment: @orome usually generic methods intention is to abstract the explicitly typing so it's a little bit against its one of the purposes.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I also included another reason why option two is preferable :)

Comment: The second example is a different type though (typo aside):  `SomeType[] | undefined`

Comment: No, there's a argument of using option two by not having to define it like this ```useState(undefined as Sometype | undefined)```